# css reading fine on mac, but not reading on PC

Tags: css, macos

I am currently working on a blog, and everything on my end (mac) is working perfectly with my html/css. However, when I send the files in a zip to a PC, the css is not reading. I've tried switching the link tag form `"style.css"` to `"/style.css"`. That did not have any effect on it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Comment: Try verify if is following the right casing, or try `./style.css`

Comment: Have you open the console on the web browser to see if there is any error in the HTML page and if the CSS file is loaded with the network tab ?
It could also be an error in the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing was wrong with the coding. The CSS formatting was rearranged and I made a rookie move of not inspecting before spending hours on google! Just had to go in and put it back to CSS format. Problem solved! Thanks guys!!